# How to get the json from a data attribute using only .attr() (or equivalent)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I feel like I am stuck on the most simple thing but I can't seem to figure out a way to solve my problem.

I have a json array that I'd like to pass to my javascript through a data attribute on a div like that:

```
<div id="scope" data-json='["apple","pear"]'></div>
```

My problem is that I can only get that value using anything BUT .data('json').

Here's a fiddle with what I'm looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/Wurielle/p17d71m0/1/

You can see in the console that logging with .data() returns a json array (which is exactly what I need) but logging with .attr() returns just plain text.
Unfortunately I can NOT use .data() for multiple reasons.

I thought about using JSON.stringify and JSON.parse but I can't get a result identical to the .data() option.

Is there any way to get the json from a data attribute using anything but .data()?

Comment: You answered it... You need to use attr("data-json") and JSON.parse()... seems weird you can not use data()

Comment: use JSON.parse? console.log(JSON.parse($('#scope').attr('data-json')));

Comment: Use `dataSet`...?

Comment: Mathijs Rutgers Thanks for your answer it actually works! I did try that before but I was logging text with my value, that's why i thought it wasn't working correctly. Silly me haha! Anyway thanks! Also @epascarello, yes it is very specific..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You have tried `JSON.parse()` and that is the answer.

```js
console.log($('#scope').attr('data-json'));

console.log($('#scope').data('json'));

console.log(JSON.parse($('#scope').attr('data-json')));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scope" data-json='["MIL","QPL"]'></div>
```

Comment: Yes it works thanks! As I said to Mathijs I was accidentaly logging other stuff with the value I used in my project, that's why I thought it wasn't working correctly.

Comment: @NoahFenghom Cool, happy to help

Answer (score 1):

Leaving jQuery out entirely, we get the same result as with `.data()`:

```js
const json    = document.getElementById('scope').dataset.json;
const decoded = JSON.parse(json);

console.log("JS-only:");
console.log(decoded);

console.log("jQuery:");
console.log($('#scope').data('json'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scope" data-json='["MIL","QPL"]'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var article = document.getElementById('scope');
var dataset = article.dataset.json;
JSON.parse(dataset);
```