# How to get these Json values?

Tags: html, jquery, json, parsing

I'm hitting a wall with this code, where I should extract some Json code within an element attribute. Here is my attempt:

```html
<div labels='[{label: "A", name: "dog"}, {label: "B", name: "cat"}]'></div>
```

```js
var labels = $("div[labels]").attr("labels");
console.log(data[0].label);
```

That was my attempt to get just the first object label, but it gives me undefined. I also tried to parse data first but I get some token error in console. What am I exactly missing here? I just want to loop through the objects and for each of them get both label and name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the json from a data attribute using only .attr() (or equivalent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43874097/how-to-get-the-json-from-a-data-attribute-using-only-attr-or-equivalent)

Comment: Yes, but how do I output single values with this notation? I'm not really familiar with square brackets on the outside rather than inside Sorry for the question

Comment: somthing like `console.log(labels [0].label);` would do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your json array keys in qoutes that will work
like this :
[{"label": "A", "name": "dog"}, {"label": "B", "name": "cat"}]

```
var labels = $("div[labels]").attr("labels");
var data = $.parseJSON(labels);
console.log(data);

OR 

var labels = $("div[labels]").attr("labels");
var data = JSON.parse(labels);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: That's what I already tried, doesn't work.

Comment: [{label: "A", name: "dog"}, {label: "B", name: "cat"}]
this array format is not correct

Comment: Thanks, would you provide some details on the most correct format this would be written in?

Comment: [{"label": "A", "name": "dog"}, {"label": "B", "name": "cat"}]

Comment: key names in qoutes

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

The issue was that keys (label, name) were missing quotes, so it was not correctly parsed.

Resolved by placing

```
var labels = data_label.attr("labels").replace(/\\n/g, "\\\n").replace(/label/gi, "\"label\"").replace(/name/gi, "\"name\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div data-labels='[{label: "A", name: "dog"}, {label: "B", name: "cat"}]'></div>
```

Javascript

```
jsonObj = eval(document.querySelector("div[data-labels]").dataset.labels)
```